# How can I get the high-res mtime for a symbolic link?

Tags: perl, symlink, stat

I want to reproduce the output of `ls --full-time` from a Perl script to avoid the overhead of calling `ls` several thousand times. I was hoping to use the [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function and grab all the information from there. However, the timestamp in the ls output uses the high-resolution clock so it includes the number of nanoseconds as well (according to the GNU docs, this is because `--full-time` is equivalent to `--format=long --time-style=full-iso`, and the full-iso time style includes the nanoseconds).

I came across the [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) module, which overrides the standard stat function with one that returns atime/mtime/ctime as floating point numbers, but there's no override for [lstat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html). This is a problem, because calling stat on a symlink returns info for the linked file, not for the link itself.

So my question is this - where can I find a version of lstat that returns atime/mtime/ctime in the same way as Time::HiRes::stat? Failing that, is there another way to get the modtime for a symlink in high resolution (other than calling ls).

Comment: Do you need a portable solution or is there just one target operating system?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use Inline::C, this will work with recent linux

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline C => <<'EOC';

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long mtime_nsec(char* fname)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (-1 == lstat(fname, &st))
        return -1;
    return (long)st.st_mtim.tv_nsec;
}
EOC

print mtime_nsec($ARGV[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to ask for `lstat` to be added to [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::HiRes).  In fact, you could probably do it yourself.  I'd bet that all you need to do is copy the function that starts

```
void
stat(...)
```

in `HiRes.xs`, change `stat(...)` to `lstat(...)` & `OP_STAT` to `OP_LSTAT`, add `lstat` to `@EXPORT_OK` in `HiRes.pm`, and recompile.  Then submit a patch so others can benefit.

Comment: Changing OP_STAT to OP_LSTAT would not work as PL_ppaddr[OP_LSTAT] is the same as PL_ppaddr[OP_STAT] since Perl_pp_lstat is internally implemented by Perl_pp_stat... But +1 for the fact that your answer gave me an idea of how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, `lstat` has been added to Time-HiRes version 1.9726 in August 2013.

See https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83356 for details.

However, it's still `1.9725` that's included in the latest stable version of `perl` as of 2014-01-31 (5.18.2). It was bumped to 1.9726 in the development version in 5.19.3 though.

Note that (as of `perl` 5.19.8), regardless of whether `Time::HiRes`'s `lstat` is *used* or not, perl's `-M`/`-A`/`-C` still don't do sub-second granularity (files with time in the same second will be shown as having the same age), so you still can't do things like `sort {-M $a <=> -M $b} @files` to sort files by modification time.

Comment: As of `perl` 5.22 (cygwin) and 5.16 (RHEL 7.2), I'm seeing differences in the 6th decimal place in the sub-second part returned by `Time::HiRes::stat` and the value returned by the `C` library `stat` function.  This causes differences in the timestamps reported by `perl` and `find -printf %TS`, for example.

Comment: This might be related to `perl` representing the timestamp as a single floating-point number vs. the `C` library representing it as two integers.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes work. This essentially contains changes to both the HiRes.pm module as well as the xs file.

**In HiRes.pm**

```
sub lstat { 
     my @lstatvalues = CORE::lstat(shift);   
     my @nanosecvalues =  Time::HiRes::lstatimplementation( $lstatvalues[8], $lstatvalues[9], $lstatvalues[10]);   
     ( $lstatvalues[8], $lstatvalues[9], $lstatvalues[10] ) = ( $nanosecvalues[0], $nanosecvalues[1], $nanosecvalues[2]);   
     return @lstatvalues;
}
```

Also added lstat to @EXPORT_OK list.

**In HiRes.xs**

```
void 
lstatimplementation(...)
PPCODE:
  UV atime = SvUV( ST( 0 ) );
  UV mtime = SvUV( ST( 1 ) );
  UV ctime = SvUV( ST( 2 ) );
  UV atime_nsec;
  UV mtime_nsec;
  UV ctime_nsec;
  hrstatns(atime, mtime, ctime,
       &atime_nsec, &mtime_nsec, &ctime_nsec);
  if (atime_nsec)
    XPUSHs( sv_2mortal(newSVnv(atime + 1e-9 * (NV) atime_nsec)));
  if (mtime_nsec)
    XPUSHs( sv_2mortal(newSVnv(mtime + 1e-9 * (NV) mtime_nsec)));
  if (ctime_nsec)
    XPUSHs( sv_2mortal(newSVnv(ctime + 1e-9 * (NV) ctime_nsec)));
```

Comment: Have you sent in a patch to [RT](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Time-HiRes)?

Comment: @BradGilbert - Not yet. I also found another way to complete this change entirely in the xs file. still deciding which would be the better option